# 1 Keystore to sign all apps or 1 per app?

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

I am wondering which is the more popular option, Having 1 keystore to sign all the apps you publish, and duplicating that keystore into the cloud and locally to keep it safe, or generating a new keystore for every new app submitted, and keeping copies of all of them?

It seems easier to have 1 keystore for everything, but despite duplicating it, im afraid of it getting corrupted and loosing access to all of the apps.

Whats the best approach for this situation?

Comment: all of the apps I've created and released for myself are signed with the same (safely backed up) key. When I do work for other people I will sign it with their key (or offer to create them one to sign it with) and I send them a copy of it.

Comment: One keystore, two keys for 6 apps here. Two keys instead of one because I wanted the certificate metadata somewhat localized.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you use the same keystore, it will be easier to make your apps work together. By having them signed with the same key, you can use a shared UID (not really recommended), or use  signature based permissions. That would make it possible to export certain data or functionality and restrict access to your own apps only (using a ContentProvider or a remote service). The downside is, that if you loose the key, you'll have to republish all apps.

If you use separate keystores, it's easier to transfer an app to someone else (give them keystore and password). Additionally, you need to re-publish only one app if you lose/corrupt the keystore.

Take you pick, but I'd say: use the same keystore and make lots of backups. I would also use physical media (CD, etc) in separate locations, rather then the 'cloud', but that's your choice too.